# The type forwarder for type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging' in assembly 'System' causes a cycle

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, .net-4.6

I am working on upgrading WPF application which is built using .Net Framework 4.6 to .Net 6. While upgrading a few assemblies, I encountered this strange issue -

> The type forwarder for type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging' in assembly 'System' causes a cycle

I have tried searching various forms but unable to find the root cause. Can anyone suggest what should be the issue?

Comment: Do any of your assemblies still depend on .NET FW 4.6?  It could be that you have conflicts between names and namespaces if you are referring to both somehow.  I should add:  When I wanted to upgrade my solution from .NET FW 4.8 to .NET 5, I found I had so much... well... "stuff" in the project files and references that it was easier to recreate the projects from scratch as .NET project and then add in the references I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming since the DLL were not compiling. I commented the code in Views and ensure that there are no errors in .cs files. Once it started compiling, the above error went away.